# Remote debugging from Intellij Idea fails with the error: Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed

Tags: java, intellij-idea, vmware, remote-debugging, jetbrains-ide

I am trying to set up Intellij remote debugging with the following conditions:

**Host machine: Mac**

There, in Intellij Idea I have the following configuration:
[image]

Now when I try to debug on the host machine, I get this:

```
Connected to the target VM, address: '172.16.253.130:57205', transport: 'socket'
Disconnected from the target VM, address: '172.16.253.130:57205', transport: 'socket'
```

**Virtual machine (running on VMware): Windows 10 & Java 8**

I add an environment variable there:

```
set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=172.16.253.130:57205
```

And then I launch the application.

And on the virtual machine I receive:

```
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 57205
Debugger failed to attach: handshake failed - connection prematurally closed
```

I have tried setting up `addres=57205` - it didn't help.
Disabled firewalls - didn't help.
I am quite lost at this point actually. Would really appreciate any kind of help from the community.

UPDATE:
Here is server.xml for the VM machine that is running the app:

```
<Server port="8055" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener"/>
  <Service name="Catalina">
    <Connector port="8080" maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
               connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8"/>
    <Connector port="8081" maxThreads="200" minSpareThreads="25" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
      connectionTimeout="-1" disableUploadTimeout="true" URIEncoding="UTF-8" scheme="https" secure="true"/>
    <Connector port="8009" enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" URIEncoding="UTF-8" secure="true"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
      <Host name="localhost" appBase="../app" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve" remoteIpHeader="x-forwarded-for" proxiesHeader="x-forwarded-by" />
        <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager" saveOnRestart="false">
          <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.FileStore"/>
        </Manager>
        <Context path="/app" useHttpOnly="false">
          <Environment name="configuration/app" value="file:C:\demo-app\app.conf" type="java.lang.String"/>
        </Context>
      </Host>
    </Engine>
  </Service>
</Server>
```

Comment: Could you please share your tomcat server.xml file?

Comment: @y.bedrov I've updated the question with `server.xml` content. Please, take a look.

Comment: Is it possible to attach idea.log ("Help | Show Log in...") after restarting IDE and reproducing the issue?